# Generate ALL Possible Combinations of Strings In One Array with space in between

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations, cartesian-product

I have the following solution that generates ALMOST all possible combinations but not ALL combinations of the strings in an array:

```
function getCombinations(chars) {
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, chars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
      f(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1));
    }
  }
  f('', chars);
  return result;
}

var combinations = getCombinations(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);
```

result is:

```
["a","ab","abc","abcd","abd","ac","acd","ad","b","bc","bcd","bd","c","cd","d"]
```

However, there are two things that I need to do but this code is not doing it:

1. The above is not really showing all the possible combinations; for example, it is not generating `"ba"` (the reverse). It is only generating `"ab"`. How can I make sure that it also generate all other combination not necessary in order of their appearance in the array?  I need the result to show combinations like `"ba", "bac", bca, "bacd", "cb",..`
2. create a space between each string once combined so the result would be:

`["a","a b","a b c","a b c d","a b d","a c","a c d","a d","b","b c","b c d","b d","c","c d","d", ...]`

Comment: You may start it over from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)